# How to remove ear name from the JNDI name

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, ear

I have an `ear` build `pom` which build api, ejb, and core java  module. But when I deploy and start the `JBoss`, it deploy  the `ejb` `JNDI` name with the ear name. For example the `JNDI` name is `server-component-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/MyServiceBean/local`

Here the MyServiceBean is my ejb that I want to lookup from `JNDI` view. and it is inside ejb module.  And my final ear name is `server-component-ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear`
 which contains

```
-lib
-META-INF
-server-component-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
-server-component-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Hear is my `ear` `pom` file

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>xxx.group.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>component-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <name>COMPONENT EAR</name>
    <artifactId>server-component-ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>xxx.group.abc</groupId>
        <artifactId>component-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xxx.group.xyz</groupId>
                <artifactId>some.artifact</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xxx.group.abc</groupId>
        <artifactId>server-component-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                 <modules>
                     <jarModule>
                        <groupId>xxx.group.abc</groupId>
                        <artifactId>component-core</artifactId>
                        <bundleDir>/</bundleDir>
                        <includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>
                    </jarModule>
                 </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
     <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                  <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[2.8,)</versionRange>
                                     <goals>
                                        <goal>generate-application-xml</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
           </plugins>
         </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Server component `pom` file which I used to run `maven build` to create the `ear`.

```
<name>SERVER COMPONENT</name>

<groupId>xxx.group.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>server-component-parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<modules>
    <module>api</module>
    <module>ejb</module>
    <module>core</module>
    <module>ear</module>
</modules>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Here is the `application.xml` in `ear`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application 1.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
<application>
  <display-name>server-component-ear</display-name>
  <module>
     <java>server-component-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
     <ejb>server-component-ejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</ejb>
  </module>
</application>
```

How can I make it to work as the `JNDI` name should only be `MyServiceBean/local`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this. [This link](http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.sg/2010/10/ejb31-global-jndi-access-portable-jndi.html) helped me to try. What I did was add the `"java:module/"` in front to the jndi lookup so that it reads the `bean` from `module` onwards. That link will help to understand it more clearly. Also note that I removed the `/local` at the end. Now I just lookup the bean only. `IService` `interface` is use by two different `beans` without any problem now.

This is how I lookup the bean from `Java SE client`.

```
String   jndi = "MyService" // this is a run time parameter. Can be 'MyAnotherService' 
IService bean = (IService) initialContext.lookup("java:module/"+jndi+"Bean");
```

And I did not change any annotation in the `bean` class. Because nothing worked for me to change the jndi name. :(

```
 @Local
 public interface IService { // interface}


 @Stateless
 public class MyServiceBean implements IService { // bean 1}


 @Stateless
 public class MyAnotherServiceBean implements IService { // bean 2}
```

Now I am not depend on the ear or my ejb jar name.
Thanks Gabriel for help!!!

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/26033585/160799 for an example that includes filtering only for modules (optimization?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I completely understand your question, but take in mind that when a session bean is deployed the server binds it to a JNDI name using a **predefined syntax**.

It seems to be that you are using ejb 3.1, if it is the case you can see a complete syntax description  [here](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr318/) (see Chapter 4, 4.4 Global JNDI Access.)

JBoss as a Java EE compliant server follows what the specification says, this is the reason why your components are binding in such way.
According to my knowledge, you are not able to change the JNDI binding name syntax.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I understood how its calling in ear environment. My issue was yesterday I converted my project from jar to ear. when I use jar I was able to lookup the bean by its name. like " MyServiceBean/local " But with the ear I can't do it anymore. Thats my issue. I did not mentioned the '@name' and '@mappedName' annotations in my bean and interface. So if I defined those I should be able to define my own JNDI name, am I?

Comment: I tried many ways. Can you guide me how to define my own JNDI name to lookup? I can not use the ejb jar name to lookup jndi. I use annotations and do not have ejb-jar.xml either. what is the solution for me?

Comment: I think it is not possible, if you now have an ear I think the best option it's to change the jndi name including the ear-name as part of it. May be [this](https://community.jboss.org/message/647139#647139) link can help you

Comment: This is very bad. Isn't it? when ever we change the ear version then we need to change the java file to lookup the bean. Is this the way the whole world work?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to overcome this issue the other way.
I have configured maven ear plugin to create version-less modules.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <version>5</version>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>/lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
        <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
        <finalName>appName-ear</finalName>
        <modules>
            <ejbModule>
                <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
                <artifactId>appName-ejb</artifactId>
                <bundleFileName>appName-ejb</bundleFileName>
            </ejbModule>
            <webModule>
                <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
                <artifactId>appName-web</artifactId>
                <bundleFileName>appName-web</bundleFileName>
            </webModule>
        </modules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: wow totally overlooked that and forgot about the Maven ear config, exactly what I needed, thanks a log @kqr !